# PHP Class best practices and class structures

Tags: php, html, web

I'm currently creating a simple CMS for my small website in PHP5. This is my first 'larger' project in PHP. First I'm creating the needed classes that would simplify me the work a little bit, and there I'm stuck. I need your opinions about the following function inside my `UserInfo` class:

```
public function setUser($id) {
        if(!isset($id)) {
            return false;
        }

        session_start();
        $conn = new mysql($_SESSION['DBCONNINFO']);
        $sql = "SELECT
                usr.ID,
                usr.USERNAME as TUSERNAME,
                usr.FIRST_NAME,
                usr.LAST_NAME,
                usr.PHONE,
                usr.MOBILE,
                usr.EMAIL,
                usr.ADDITIONAL_INFO,
                usr.LAST_LOGIN_DATE,
                usr.USER_GROUP_ID
                FROM cms_users usr
                WHERE usr.id = " . $id;

        $result = $conn->query_cust($sql);
        $conn=null;

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $this->id = $row['usr']['ID'];
            $this->username = $row['usr']['TUSERNAME'];
            $this->firstname = $row['usr']['FIRST_NAME'];
            $this->lastname = $row['usr']['LAST_NAME'];
            $this->phone = $row['usr']['PHONE'];
            $this->mobile = $row['usr']['MOBILE'];
            $this->email = $row['usr']['EMAIL'];
            $this->additional_info = $row['usr']['ADDITIONAL_INFO'];
            $this->last_login_date = $row['usr']['LAST_LOGIN_DATE'];
            $this->user_group = $row['usr']['USER_GROUP_ID'];
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Am I doing it the right way, I'm not talking about the syntax, for now I focus on the class structure, design and best practices - any opinion would be appreciated.

Could I call the `session_start()`, for example, in the class constructor and use the vars inside it without calling it each time in a function !?

Should I close the DB connection via the `close()` function or is `$conn=null` acceptable !?

Is it a bad practice to store the database information in the session class !? If yes, where to store it as a 'global' variable - $_GLOBAL !?

If there is a 'PHP bes practice class structures in 5 minutes for dummies' please notify me :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read through this set of articles: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: @igorw Wow, that article is very interresting. I was already doing dependency injection for a long time but didn't know it was called that way. It makes sense for me to use that route, i suggest AlenBer to follow this even if it can be quite technical on the architectural level but simple at the coding level

Answer (score 0):

Use `define` to define all of your constants.
For example:

```
define('DBCONNINFO', "something");
```

Also you only have to call `session_start()` once, it can be done anywhere in your script.

Comment: Well, the `$_SESSION['DBCONNINFO']` array data is defined in a INI file on the file system from which I read the information and store into the session, so could I do the same and store the data as a 'define' constant !?

Comment: @AlenBer well you can't save arrays with `define`, but you can turn the array to strings and back again with `json_*code` or the `*plode` functions

Comment: I'd rather use class constants than pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to fetch the data from the database for every request if you're using sessions anyway. In which case, why is session_start() being called inside the setUser() method?

And we can't really comment on the class structure when you've only provided a single method.

Also, since the representation of data leaving PHP should be appropriate to the substrate where that data is going (to prevent SQL injection, email header injection, CSS....) then it's good practice to defer changes to the representation of the data until just before the point where it leaves PHP. e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT
       ....
            WHERE usr.id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

(or use bound parameters)

However since users are usually identify themselves by their username rather than their userid, it rather implies that $id came from somewhere other than user supplied data - in which case where? And why are you using this as the identifier when you've already got an identifier for the session (which is where this data should be getting stored).

Or do you want to use this class for processing data relating to users other than the user of the current session - in which case there is *no way* that there should be a session_start() in there.

Sorry - but this is not well thought out code and not a well presented question.

BTW, setting the connection to null does not close the database connection.

Comment: That's the reason I posted the question. I'm not sure how to structure the classes, for example, a simple user management form. So I stared with the UserInfo class and just added a singe function to retrieve data form the database via the users unique ID. The rest of the class-code are just the defined vars (username, firstname, lastname.. etc).